# Selecting data from 3 tables with limit

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 3 tables ppc_offers, survery_offers,find_offers ( from admin section, i enter data into these tables)

Now on front end, i want to display latest 3 offers from these tables.

i.e. latest 3 will come, they can be from single table or multiple tables... it just has condition "latest 3"

How can i do this?

Laravel provides any way to do this?

or do i need to have any master table?

or can you suggest me regular SQL query for this?

Please help.
Thanks.

PPC Table:

```
-------------------------
id            |  integer
title         |  varchar
url           |  varchar
description   |  varchar
created_at    |  timestamp
updated_at    |  timestamp
--------------------------
```

survey Table:

```
-------------------------
id            |  integer
title         |  varchar
created_at    |  timestamp
updated_at    |  timestamp
--------------------------
```

find code Table:

```
-------------------------
id            |  integer
title         |  varchar
url           |  varchar
description   |  varchar
code          |  varchar
created_at    |  timestamp
updated_at    |  timestamp
--------------------------
```

Comment: post the collumns inside each table

Comment: Why do you have 3 tables instead of one?

Comment: table structure added, pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a recommendation, it might make more sense to include all 3 of these offers in one table, and use an "offer_type" id to distinguish them from each other, instead of using 3 different tables. It might simplify your code.

I believe this may work with your current setup:

```
$ppc = DB::table('ppc_offers')
  ->select('title', 'url', 'description', 'NULL as code', 'updated_at');

$survey = DB::table('survey_offers')
  ->select('title', 'NULL as url', 'NULL as description', 'NULL as code', 'updated_at');

$find = DB::table('find_offers')
  ->select('title', 'url', 'description', 'code', 'updated_at');

return $ppc->unionAll($survey)->unionAll($find)
  ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
  ->take(3)
  ->get();
```

Comment: but will i be able to get other columns in these tables?
for example: find has a column `code`

Comment: @cnu ok, I think i figured it out with the code above.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your hardwork
If i have another table where i will list all offers (of any type) declined by user, will i be able to add that condition as well here?
i.e. if user declined an offer before, we should not show it again
or its better to go with single table for all offer types

Comment: @cnu '$ppc->unionAll($survey)->unionAll($find)' basically does the job of temporarily combining your 3 tables for you. You can add any additional clauses to that if you want. So if that constraint can be done in a simple where clause, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Make 3 queries union them with the same names for columns

```
select * from

(
 (query1 order by id desc limit 3) x
   union
(query2 order by id desc limit 3) y
   union
(query3 order by id desc limit 3) z
```

(